# CSS: Font-face not working on Chrome

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, truetype

How can I tell why the font is not being displayed?

I'm in Chrome - so .ttf should work.
I checked that I can navigate to the file using my URL bar, and I can download it so permissions are fine.

I have a page that declares a @font-face:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  src: url('/css/fonts/entypo.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

p { font-family: 'entypo'; }
```

Comment: Nice. I did that, and I can download the font file fine.

Comment: Hit F12 to open up the web inspector. Click the 'Resources' tab. Expand 'Frames', and the folder named after your page. Is there a fonts folder there? Is your font in there? Now open the 'Network' tab. Reload your page. Does your font appear in the list? A few checks like this will make it easier to work out what the problem is.

Comment: Theoretically, this *should* be working.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site? Would help us to debug it.

Comment: And it's working in other browsers?

Comment: Link provided. No the font does not work in any browser.

Comment: Just plain clicking the link to your site, my browser froze while loading it.

Comment: I also face the same problem where FF shows the font perfectly and Chrome (as always) make problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @font-face cannot be within a block. Common practice is to have it at the top of the CSS file.

Your source:

```css
#lookgram {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'entypo';
    src: url("/entypo.eot");
    src: url("/entypo.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/entypo.woff") format("woff"), url("/entypo.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/entypo.svg#entypo") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'entypo_social';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("/css/fonts/entypo-social.woff") format("woff");
  }

  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug with chrome relating to web-font as ive had a similar problem. Its worth noting the article at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984543/google-chrome-bug-website-not-displaying-text. The article gives a few ideas as how but not why this bug is occurring - and at times fairly random!

Hope this helps